# Remove space under navbar (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm trying to remove the space between my navbar and a picture I've got under the menu.

I've tried to play around with margin-top/margin-bottom Also I have tried to edit .navbar{margin-bottom: 20px;} in bootstrap.min.css which didn't help either.

My HTML code looks like this

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="logo"><a href="Index.php"> <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Greenterapi/Pics/Logo.png" alt="Home" width="200px" height="74px"></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <div class="btn btn-primary">Menu</div>
                    </button>

                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="Index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Om.php">Om mig</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Coaching.php">Coaching</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Psykoterapi.php">Psykoterapi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Zoneterapi.php">Zoneterapi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Erhverv.php">Erhverv</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Priser.php">Priser</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav> </div>


    </div>






<!--Row with 1 column in 1:1 ratio-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="Header"><img src="http://placehold.it/1140x250"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have not got any css code that effects the menu, or the picture, except for this

```
ul.nav a:hover { background-color: #555; color: #030303 !important; }
```

I hope your able to help, I'm out of ideas.

**Edit** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOMRGV as per request

**Edit 2** Seems like it's working with the use of a br tag and margin-bottom thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Here's a fiddle you could use: http://jsfiddle.net/80qjng5o/1/ You can see that I've adjusted the `margin-bottom` to 0 and it does change, so something else is superseding the attempt to set the `margin-bottom` to 0.

Comment: It's not quite what I need - Theres still at space between the navbar and the placehold picture I've got under it

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGZxOB. Looks like it has to be something else later on in the CSS that is resetting the `margin-bottom` setting back to 20px, if you did still see the gap after changing the margin in bootstrap's CSS.

You should use the element inspector in any major browser by pressing F12 on the keyboard. Then you can inspect the element and look at all the CSS rules that are affecting that `.navbar`.

Comment: It looks like the margin-bottom: 0; overrides the margin-bottom: 20; that's default in bootstrap, (which is exactly what I want) when looking at the css rules thats affecting the .navbar, could it be the row under my menu that's making a margin, or padding between the two elements?

Comment: I was using Firefox for the CodePen. However, in Chrome, IE, Safari, and Edge, they all put a placeholder for the image. The image height is 74px, which is what is pushing the following elements below the image and menu down. In Firefox, no placeholder is included and that's why the following elements are snug against the bottom of the menu. If you remove the height of the image, things tighten up.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ECECEA;
}
div.haj {
  background-color: #ff390d;
}
div.InfoTekst,
div.Info {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
ul.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #030303 !important;
}
.navbar.navbar-static-top {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.navbar.navbar-static-top,
.navbar-nav li a {
  height: 74px;
}
#brand-logo {
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#brand-logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 74px;
}
.navbar-static-top .navbar-brand {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-nav {
    background: #ECECEA;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-nav li a {
    height: auto;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-static-top {
    height: 74px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
#brand-logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 74px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-nav li {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
      <div id="brand-logo">
        <a href="Index.php">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x74/555/fff?text=Home" alt="Home" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

            <div class="btn btn-primary">Menu</div>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a z href="Index.php">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Om.php">Om mig</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Coaching.php">Coaching</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Psykoterapi.php">Psykoterapi</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Zoneterapi.php">Zoneterapi</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Erhverv.php">Erhverv</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Priser.php">Priser</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Row with 1 column in 1:1 ratio-->
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1140x250/f00/fff" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <!--Row with two columns divided in 1:3 ratio-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="InfoTekst">
            <p>
              <h3>Velkommen til Green Terapi</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
              aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="InfoTekst">
            <p>
              <h3>Coaching</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
              aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="InfoTekst">
            <p>
              <h3>Psykoterapi</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
              aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="InfoTekst">
            <p>
              <h3>Zoneterapi</h3> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
              aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
      <div class="Info">
        <p>
          <p class="Billede">
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Greenterapi/profile.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:160px;height:160px">
          </p>
          <h5>
                    Coach
                </h5>

          <h5>
                    Psykoterapeut
                </h5>

          <h5>
                    Zoneterapeut
                </h5>

          <p>Jeanette Green</p>
          <p>Tlf.: 22 11 26 39</p>
          <br>
          <p> <b>
                        mail@green-terapi.dk
                    </b>

          </p>
          <p>Motion & Sundhedshuset
            <br>Egedal 15
            <br>2690 Karlslunde</p>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the default settings for ul and a. Probably has margin, padding, which you'd need to override for the navbar section.

Comment: Do you mean in the bootstrap css?

Comment: Whichever has the rules regarding navbar.